# Point of intersection of reciprocal and logx function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came through a question of area(calculus)  which demanded me to find out the point of intersection of reciprocal(1/x) curve and log(base e ) curve. I tried but came up with no  satisfactory conclusion. Please help me out....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want (or cannot) use the magnificant Lambert function, consider that solving $\frac 1x=\log(x)$ is the same as finding the zero of function
$$f(x)=x \log(x)-1$$ Its derivatives are
$$f'(x)=1+\log(x) \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac 1x >0 \qquad\forall x $$ The first derivative cancels when $x=\frac 1e$ and then the minimum of the function is $f\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)=-1-\frac{1}{e}$.

To get an *approximate* solution, develop $f(x)$ as a trucated Taylor series built at $x=\frac 1e$. You would get
$$f(x)=-\left(1+\frac{1}{e}\right)+\frac{1}{2} e
   \left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{e}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms and solving for $0$ would give
$$x_0=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{\sqrt{2(1+ e)}}{e}\approx 1.37109 $$ Now, you have all elements to use (as the simplest) Newton method which will generate the iterates according to
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{\log (x_n)+1}$$ that is to say
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.3710890148977450487 \\
 1 & 1.8022798851710778477 \\
 2 & 1.7634911021396245675 \\
 3 & 1.7632228473717156460 \\
 4 & 1.7632228343518967409 \\
 5 & 1.7632228343518967102
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Comment: Actually i am a novice would you make me aware of taylor series??

Comment: @AayushSingh. Don't worry ! You will learn that quite soon and I am sure that you will enjoy Taylor expansions. In short, you make a local approximation of the function using polynomials (just visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). I felt in love with them more than 60 years ago and I use them almost every day. Cheers and good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y = \frac{1}{x}\\
y = \ln x\\
\frac{1}{x} = \ln x\\
$$

Let $w=\frac{1}{x}$.

$$
w = \ln w^{-1}\\
w = - \ln w\\
-w = \ln w\\
e^{-w} = w\\
1 = w e^w\\
$$

See [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant). More generally for problems like this Lambert W-function.